# My RSS feeds are not working on my HTTPS home page

Tags: https, rss

My RSS feeds are not working on my home page after I changed my site to all HTTPS (ex. https://www.colonialstock.com).  Any ideas why and how to fix this?  I use dynamic drive for my feed display code.  All of the code is on the home page.

Here are the errors from Google/Chrome developer tools:

```html
yui-min.js:12 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.colonialstock.com/index.htm' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss(0%2C2)%2…es.org%2Falltables.env&callback=YUI.Env.JSONP.yui_3_18_1_2_1493852745498_2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
_insert @ yui-min.js:12
yui-min.js:12 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.colonialstock.com/index.htm' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss(0%2C2)%2…es.org%2Falltables.env&callback=YUI.Env.JSONP.yui_3_18_1_3_1493852745498_2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
_insert @ yui-min.js:12
yui-min.js:12 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.colonialstock.com/index.htm' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss(0%2C1)%2…es.org%2Falltables.env&callback=YUI.Env.JSONP.yui_3_18_1_4_1493852745498_2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
_insert @ yui-min.js:12
indicator.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```